# Footer not showing full width despite class="container-fluid"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My footer isn't quite making it full width despite the class of container-fluid being added.

Please see:

http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk

**HTML**

```
<footer class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 footercta">
      <h4 class="bottomoffer">Sign up to access your free Jumpstart your Finances email course</h4>
      <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup2">
<form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div>


                   <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" class="handarrow hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom"></div>

</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 footerlinks">
    <br>
    <ul class="mylist">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mylist2">
    <li>Facebook</li>
    <li>Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  </div>
  <br> 
  <br>
   <div class="finalfooterlinks"><p>
  Privacy Policy | Terms of Service</p>

  <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 -
<script type="text/javascript">
    now = new Date
    theYear=now.getYear()
    if (theYear < 1900)
    theYear=theYear+1900
    document.write(theYear)
</script></div>
<br>

</footer>
```

Can't quite seem to figure it out, code validates 100% so I'm sure it's not an open `<div>`.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not full-width?

Comment: It's not the footer! The footer is as wide as it should be; as wide as the body. The problem is that something else (I can't seem to find what) is making the document wider than the window. Oh, and you should reevaluate your bold statement about the code validating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `padding-left: 9.6%` on the `.col-sm-7`. If you lose that, it stretches full width. Well... the left side goes to the edge, you'll have to do something else to get the right side to spread out. Might I suggest checking out flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yes it's the right side that's the issue, I'm using Bootstrap BTW

Comment: Please note I have it working on other pages without using flexbox please see: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/privacy-policy.html

Comment: Not sure how wide you want the right column to be but you could change  '.col-sm-5' to '.col-sm-4' and add 'pull-right' class to it and that should get the right side stretching too.